# Bartender Software HTML Barcode doesn't show in label preview

Tags: jquery, html, barcode, bartender

For my Bartender label I've created a HTML to display in the Markup Language Text tool.
When I view the HTML code separately in browser it displays the bar-code correctly.
[image]

But when I preview the label it doesn't show the bar-code.

[image]

Can't I refer the red highlighted URLs through Bartender? I'm guessing that's why the bar-code doesn't appear since I used jQuery to display the bar-code.

Bartender markup filed properties.
[image]

Comment: Can you show a picture of the settings in the barcode?

Comment: Sorry I didn't't get you. Barcode setting where? In BT I've only used a Markup Language field.

Comment: Can you show me the properties of that field?

Comment: @Wouter I added the properties for the markup filed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.
See the following link: http://help.seagullscientific.com/2019/en/Index.htm#Supported_HTMLTags.htm

I can see you connect the field to a database. If this database contains the data you can just create a barcode and connect the Databasefield to it.